# How to generate random string of alphanumeric characters of set length into a html <span>?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to randomly generate a barcode with a font on page load. I want the length to be 36 characters long, consisting of only 0-9, a-z and A-Z. I want to have a <span> print the generated string. The code I have currently generates the random string, but it's printing it at the top of the page. I also want to do this with the AUTH and TOKN numbers as well, only with 10 characters of 0-9 and a-z. I currently have those two working as randomly generated 10-character numbers, but as I said, that's not what I want to do in the long run. Here is my current code.

```js
function showRandomNumber() {
  document.getElementById("authnumber").innerHTML =
    Math.round(Math.random() * (9999999999 - 1000000000) + 1000000000);
  document.getElementById("tokennumber").innerHTML =
    Math.round(Math.random() * (9999999999 - 1000000000) + 1000000000);
}

function randomString(length, chars) {
  var result = '';

  for (var i = length; i > 0; --i)
    result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];

  return result;
}
document.write(randomString(36, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'));

randomString();
showRandomNumber();
```

```css
#barcode {
  font-family: "Code 128";
  font-size: 44.5px;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(.73);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(.73);
  transform: scaleY(.73);
  float: left;
}

#myNumber {
  margin: 2px;
  font-family: "OCR A Extended", "OCR A";
  font-size: 16.75px;
  margin-top: 6.5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="warning_menu_container" style="margin-top:7px; margin-bottom:-11px;">
  <span id="barcode" style="margin-top:-7px; ">insert random string of text here 01</span>
  <span id="myNumber">AUTH:<font color="1fa779"><span id="authnumber" style="align:right;"></span></font>
  </span><br />
  <span id="myNumber" style="line-height: 1.1;">TOKN:<font color="1fa779"><span id="tokennumber"></span></font>
  </span>
</div>
```

I've tried the code I currently have written up, as shown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate random string/characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: Do **not** use `document.write()`. Populate your `span` element (by DOM manipulation) the same way you already do for "authnumber" and "tokennumber".

Comment: I already figured not to use that, I stole that part of the code from elsewhere. I'm asking how to print that result to the barcode <span> instead of using that. Do you know how I would do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply remove the line for `document.write(...)` and only call the `randomString()` function during the onload event.

Something along the lines of:

```js
function showRandomNumber() {
  document.getElementById("authnumber").innerHTML =
    Math.round(Math.random() * (9999999999 - 1000000000) + 1000000000);
  document.getElementById("tokennumber").innerHTML =
    Math.round(Math.random() * (9999999999 - 1000000000) + 1000000000);

  // use randomString() for barcode??
  document.getElementById("barcode").innerHTML =
    randomString(36, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
}

function randomString(length, chars) {
  var result = '';

  for (var i = length; i > 0; --i)
    result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];

  return result;
}
// show all numbers
showRandomNumber();
```

```css
#barcode {
  font-family: "Code 128";
  font-size:24px;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(.73);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(.73);
  transform: scaleY(.73);
  float: left;
  margin-top: -7px;
}

#myNumber {
  margin: 2px;
  font-family: "OCR A Extended", "OCR A";
  font-size: 16.75px;
  margin-top: 6.5px;
  color: #1fa779;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
```

```html
<div class="warning_menu_container">
  <div id="barcode"></div>

  <div id="myNumber">
    AUTH: <span id="authnumber"></span>
  </div>

  <div id="myNumber">
    TOKN:<span id="tokennumber"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I print the "randomString" to the "insert random string of text here 01" part? Because at the moment, that only removes the random string from the top of the page, rendering it inert.

Comment: sure, just add another `getElementById()`... let me add that to the answer

Comment: while that works to change the barcode, it's only in 10-character numerical values, not the alphanumeric I had stated.

Comment: sure, then use the other function for the value... see update

Comment: thank you, that works! I've modified it to print the AUTH and TOKN code to get that result as well. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad I could help